# Как правильно написать функцию, чтобы она считала сумму вводимых чисел

Tags: python

Я ввожу первое число, которое в свою очередь говорит мне сколько последующих цифр я хочу ввести с клавиатуры. Потом создаю функцию, чтобы посчитать сумму этих цифр:

```
def suma_digits_a(a):
    for i in range(a):
        x = int(input(' '))
        s = x
        s += x
        print(s)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = int(input('введите число: '))

    print(suma_digits_a(a))
```

к примеру я ввожу число 3, потом числа 3, 3, 3 и должен получить сумму 9, а у меня они не суммируются.

Comment: Читайте, пожалуйста, свой код. Можно было бы не попасть в такую ситуацию, если проговорить каждую строчку кода. А также хорошо бы перечитать собственные заметки урока и пересмотреть учебные примеры. Никто никогда бы не дал непосильное задание.

Answer (score 2):

**ошибка №1:**

Функция `suma_digits_a` ничего не возвращает а когда функция в питоне ничего не возвращает, то считается, что она возвращает `None`

Однако вы выводите результат внутри функции, а затем делаете

```
print(suma_digits_a(a))
```

т.е. выводите результат работы функции `suma_digits_a`, т.е. `None`

Вам надо не выводить в функции сумму, а вернуть ее:

```
def suma_digits_a(a):
    # ваш код
    return sum
```

**ошибка №2:**

вы не вычисляете сумму, поскольку внутри цикла постоянно присваиваете сумме последнее значение

```
for i in range(a):
    x = int(input(' '))
    s = x
    s += x
    print(s)
```

в итоге таким подходом вы просто в конечном итоге удаиваете введенное значение

```
    s = x
    s += x
```

вынесете `s` из цикла

```
s = 0
for i in range(a):
    x = int(input(' '))
    s += x
```

**непонятка №3**

а зачем вам вот этот код?

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
```

**P.S.**
Если не стоит задача сначала запросить сколько чисел будет, а затем вводить эти числа, то можно обойтись гораздо более короткими техниками:

1. получить все введенные в одной строке числа в массив через функцию `map`

   ```
    nums = [*map(int, input().split())]
   ```
2. подсчитать сумму через функцию `reduce`

   ```
    from functools import reduce

    nums = [*map(int, input().split())]
    sum = reduce(lambda sum, value: sum + value, nums)

    print(sum)
   ```
3. воспользоваться функцией `sum`:

   ```
    nums = [*map(int, input().split())]
    res = sum(nums)

    print(sum)
   ```

Comment: Спасибо за такой развернутый ответ!